# Python connect to Teradata in AWS EC2

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, odbc, teradata

I want to pull data from a Teradata instance. Client code runs Python2.7+ on AWS EC2 instance.

I installed unixODBC driver and `sudo pip install teradata` but I am still getting the following exception:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py", line 369, in determineDriver
"Available drivers: {}".format(dbType, ",".join(drivers)))
teradata.api.InterfaceError: ('DRIVER_NOT_FOUND', "No driver found for 'Teradata'.  Available drivers: PostgreSQL,MySQL")
```

The code is as follows:

```
import sys
import teradata
# my own imports
td = TeradataClient(DEFAULT_HOSTNAME, DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_PASSWORD)
td.select(query, outfile)
```

The `TeradataClient` class I created which calls Teradata is as follows:

```
class TeradataClient:
    def __init__(self, hostname, username, password):
        self._hostname = hostname
        self._username = username
        self._password = password
        self._udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="MyApp", version="1.0", logConsole=False)


    def select(self, query, outfile, sep=DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, nullstr=DEFAULT_NULL_STR):
        with self._udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system=self._hostname, username=self._username,
                                          password=self._password) as session:
            print 'Connection to Teradata established'
            with open(outfile,'w') as fp:
                with session.cursor() as cursor:
                    for row in cursor.execute(query):
                        lineparts = [str(x if x!=None else nullstr) for x in row]
                        fp.write('%s\n' %sep.join(lineparts))
```

How can I fix this? Is there another ODBC driver that needs to be installed?

Comment: maybe boto? [link](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3998)

Comment: `boto3` is already installed.

Comment: Please post attempted connection string. It could be a very minor syntax or missing attribute. And please add all `import` lines.

Comment: @Parfait: posted the code. The same code is working perfectly on Macbook. It only crashes on Linux systems. So there is some problem kicking off the correct driver.

Answer (score 4):

This fixed the issue for me:

```
export ODBC_VERSION=14.10
export ODBCINI=/opt/teradata/client/$ODBC_VERSION/odbc_64/odbc.ini 
export ODBCINSTINI=/opt/teradata/client/$ODBC_VERSION/odbc_64/odbcinst.ini
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/teradata/client/$ODBC_VERSION/odbc_64/lib:/opt/teradata/client/$ODBC_VERSION/tdicu/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export NLSPATH=/opt/teradata/client/$ODBC_VERSION/odbc_64/msg/tdodbc.cat
```

**note:**

- change `$ODBC_VERSION` as needed.
- update `/etc/resolv.conf` for the `system` kwarg in `udaExec.connect`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today and found that it is caused by one of the latest versions of the teradata python package.  Installing version 15.10.0.10 with pip allowed me to connect from my RHEL instance.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I switched to using the REST interface so I didn't have to deal with drivers altogether. Much better now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install the Teradata ODBC driver.

Available on the Teradata Developer Exchange.
http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity

Comment: I have the driver installed but it is not showing up in the list of the drivers.

Comment: Could it be the drivers are 64 bit and python is 32 bit (or vice versa)?
That can cause the drivers to not show up in Windows, not sure about Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am about 2 years late, but I had the same issue today and found a solution to it. Please go to /usr/lib64 and check the following two symlinks:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Oct 18 10:56 libodbcinst.so -> libodbcinst.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Oct 18 10:56 libodbcinst.so.2 -> libodbcinst.so.2.0.0
```

If they don't point to teradata, it will not work! They should point to the teradata odbc installation dir:

Fix (use at your own risk, without any warrenty) ;):

```
sudo rm /usr/lib64/libodbc.so
sudo rm /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so
sudo ln -s /opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64/libodbc.so /usr/lib64/libodbc.so
sudo ln -s /opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64/libodbcinst.so /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so
```

The result:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Oct 25 20:10 libodbcinst.so -> /opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64/libodbcinst.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Oct 25 20:10 libodbc.so -> /opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64/libodbc.so
```

And voilá, the connection to Teradata should be running smooth as butter!